# What needs to be done, based on the following in order to successfully boot into the system?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, lvm, systemd-journald, system-failure

Ran this command:

```
sudo fsck -fvy /dev/mapper/root_vg-home
```

Here's the output:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.30
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30Dec-2021)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/mapper/root_vgx2dhome
```

Possibly non-existent device?